# How to access Interface method implemented in the derived class from child class?

Tags: c#, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I have two interfaces A,B both has same method declarations. I have a class C inheriting from interfaces A,B. I have another class D inheriting from C. Now i want to access the  implemented methods in C from D

```
interface A
{
    int add(int x, int y);
    int mul(int x, int y);
}

interface B
{
    int add(int x, int y);
    int mul(int x, int y);
}

public class C : A,B
{
    int A.add(int x,int y)
    {
        return x + y;
    }

    int A.mul(int x,int y)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    int B.add(int x, int y)
    {
        return x;
    }

    int B.mul(int x, int y)
    {
        return y;
    }  
}


class D : C
{
}
```

How to access the methods in C from D?

Comment: As an aside, your question would be better if you used conventional names - an `I` prefix for interfaces, PascalCase for the methods etc. I know they're just example names, but following conventions reduces cognitive load.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How to access the methods in C from D?

You have to use a reference with a compile-time of the relevant interface. For example:

```
class D
{
    public void FooA()
    {
        A a = this;
        Console.WriteLine(a.mul(...));
    }

    public void FooB()
    {
        B b = this;
        Console.WriteLine(b.mul(...));
    }
}
```

Of course you don't need the local variable - you can cast:

```
Console.WriteLine(((A) this).mul(...));
```

... but it gets a bit ugly.

This is just because you're using [explicit interface implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx). If you implemented one of the interfaces *implicitly*, you could just call the methods directly as normal... but explicit interface implementation only allows a member to be called via that interface.

Answer (score 3):

An explicit interface method invocation should always work

```
((A)this).mul(1,1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code because you have to specify the interface from which you want to use the method (A or B):

```
((A)this).add(1, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

As others already suggested casting is of course one way of doing this. It's quick and simple but if you're going to use it a lot it's annoying. The way out in this case are properties that give access to the members provided by the interface and that conveniently *group*  them thus simplifying their usage:

Easy access without additional casting (you do it only once inside the property getters - see below the `C`-class):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        C c = new C();
        c.As.add(1, 2);
    }
}
```

Interfaces:

```
public interface A
{
    int add(int x, int y);
    int mul(int x, int y);
}

public interface B
{
    int add(int x, int y);
    int mul(int x, int y);
}
```

**`C`**-class:

```
public class C : A, B
{
    // Methods from the A-interface.
    public A As { get { return (A)this; } }

    // Methods from the B-interface.
    public B Bs { get { return (B)this; } }

    int A.add(int x, int y)
    {
        return x + y;
    }
    int A.mul(int x, int y)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    int B.add(int x, int y)
    {
        return x;
    }
    int B.mul(int x, int y)
    {
        return y;
    }
}
```

**`D`**-class:

```
public class D : C
{
    public D()
    {
        base.As.add(1, 2);
        base.Bs.add(3, 4);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check this,

```
 using System;

 public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
     {

     D ds=new D(10,12);

     int valueAddtion=((A)ds).add(20,122);

     int valueMultiplication=((B)ds).mul(20,11);
     Console.WriteLine("Mainapplicatin Value  of A= " +valueAddtion+" multiplication value=  "+valueMultiplication);

    }
}
```

// your code segment here

```
 class D : C
 {
  public D()
  {
 int valueAdd=((A)this).add(10,11);
 int valueMul=((B)this).mul(20,11); 
 Console.WriteLine("Addition Value  of A= " +valueAdd+" multiplication value= "+valueMul);
  }

public D(int x,int y):this()
{
 int valueAdd=((A)this).add(x,y);
 int valueMul=((B)this).mul(x,y);   
 Console.WriteLine("Paremeterized Value  of A= " +valueAdd+" multiplication value= "+valueMul);
}
}
```

Output will be,

Addition Value  of A= 21 multiplication value= 11

Paremeterized Value  of A= 22 multiplication value= 12

Mainapplicatin Value  of A= 142 multiplication value= 11